# What privileges do I have to grant to allow a user to select from information_schema.table_privileges?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm using MS SQL Server 2008, and I am trying to get a complete listing of all privileges assigned to all grantees by running this query:

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_PRIVILEGES
```

However, right now I'm only getting back records associated with the "public" grantee. I've tried adding the db_owner role to this user account, and I've also run this query within the database:

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO myuser
```

Neither of these actions has changed the response from the above query - still only getting public grantee records. What is the minimum setting I need to do to grant the user the rights to all the records?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [information_schema view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186233.aspx) (my bold)

> Returns one row for each table privilege that is granted to or granted by the current **user** in the current database.

This doesn't take into account roles etc: it all works on `DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID` which can be seen if you look at the definition of INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_PRIVILEGES

Personally, I'd just use [sys.database_permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188367.aspx) and not bother with the information_schema rubbish. This relies solely on M[eta data visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113.aspx) to filter rows, so you'll see the actual permissions *unfiltered* by the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_PRIVILEGES view which adds a further filter that bollixes you.

For completeness, here is the view. Note the implicit "old style" JOIN :-)

```
CREATE VIEW INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_PRIVILEGES
AS
SELECT  
    USER_NAME(p.grantor_principal_id)   AS GRANTOR,
    USER_NAME(p.grantee_principal_id)   AS GRANTEE,
    DB_NAME()                       AS TABLE_CATALOG,
    SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id)            AS TABLE_SCHEMA,
    o.name                          AS TABLE_NAME,
    convert(varchar(10), CASE p.type
        WHEN 'RF' THEN 'REFERENCES'
        WHEN 'SL' THEN 'SELECT'
        WHEN 'IN' THEN 'INSERT'
        WHEN 'DL' THEN 'DELETE'
        WHEN 'UP' THEN 'UPDATE'
        END)                        AS PRIVILEGE_TYPE,
    convert(varchar(3), CASE p.state
        WHEN 'G' THEN 'NO'
        WHEN 'W' THEN 'YES'
        END)                        AS IS_GRANTABLE
FROM
    sys.objects o,
    sys.database_permissions p
WHERE
    o.type IN ('U', 'V')
    AND p.class = 1
    AND p.major_id = o.object_id
    AND p.minor_id = 0  -- all columns
    AND p.type IN ('RF','IN','SL','UP','DL')
    AND p.state IN ('W','G')
    AND (p.grantee_principal_id = 0
        OR p.grantee_principal_id = DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID()
        OR p.grantor_principal_id = DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID())
```

Comment: I don't understand - are you saying the user must be specifically granted permission to the "information_schema.table_privileges" view?

Comment: No, see my update. It doesn't take into account role membership because it's *stupid*. Don't use it.

Comment: I was able to change my code to use the sys views, and it works well.  Thanks for your help.